# WebClient.UploadValues to API. How do I get the posted values in the API?

Tags: c#, web-services, api

Good day,

I am sending data to an API using WebClient as seen in another post:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
      var values = new NameValueCollection();
      values["thing1"] = "hello";
      values["thing2"] = "world";

      client.Headers.Add("Username", Store.Objects.Application.Username());
      client.Headers.Add("PassToken", Store.Objects.Application.User()["PassToken"].ToString());

      var response = client.UploadValues(Store.Objects.Application.API_URL() + "/Company/Add", values);

      var responseString = Encoding.Default.GetString(response);
}
```

My problem is I can't get the values posted in the API:

```
[HttpPost]
public Store.Objects.Security.Account Add(NameValueCollection values)
{
}
```

How do I access the sent values?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have anything in `values`? FYI `HttpPost` is just shorthand for `AcceptVerbs`, you don't need both.

Comment: values are empty...Edited the HttpPost part thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have known there to be issues mapping key/value type collections such as `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` because it clashes with the `RouteValueDictionary` - to avoid this it's generally best to put the appropriate parameters into the method signature and let the MVC binder deal with the mapping. In your case, try changing your method signature to

```
[HttpPost]
public Store.Objects.Security.Account Add(string thing1, string thing2)
{
}
```